# What's the state of XCMP, and how does it compare to AWM

Tags: xcmp

I'm trying to read about XCMP but documentation is a bit confusing as, 1. It doesn't exist yet, 2. development is hard to follow.

I was mainly curious as to how it compares to AWM, as both seem to (in a very basic explanation) use p2p communication between blockchains/parachains/subnets. I'm trying to better understand the differences between them, as well as when XCMP will be available.